# What is the Frechet derivative of $(u^+)^q$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

I know that if we define $E[u]=\int_\Omega u^+dx$, where $\Omega$ is compact in $R^n$ and $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, $u^+:=\max\{u,0\}$, then $E[u]$ is not Frechet differentiable. However, if now I define $E[u]=\int_\Omega (u^+)^qdx$, for some $q>2$, then is it $E$ is Frechet differentiable?(all other setting are same). If yes, what is it? Thank you!

Comment: The derivative at $u$ is given by $h\mapsto \int_{\Omega} q(u^+)^{q-1} h$, if it exists. I think it exists for $q\ge 2$, as long as $q$ is not too large (so that $E[u]$ stays finite).

Comment: @youcancallmeAl Thank you for your answer. But, could you remind me that why $u^+$ is not freshet differentiable, but $(u^+)^q$ is?

Comment: Did you tried to prove it @user124358? Could you supply us with your work?

Comment: @Tomás Sure. Please see the comment below

Answer (score 0):

@Tomas

Sure, let me first show $u^+$ is not Fréchet differentiable. By definition I need to prove that, for some $DE(u)\in H_0^1(\Omega)=X$, we need to have
\begin{equation}
\frac{|E(u+v)-E(u)-DE(u)v|}{\|v\|_X}\to 0,
\end{equation}
as $\|v\|\to0$.
Then, consider the definition of $E$, we need to prove
\begin{equation}
\frac{\left|\int (u+v)^+-\int u^+-\int \chi_{u^+}v\right|}{\|v\|_X}\to 0.
\end{equation}
However, the above limit can not be true for example if we choose $v_n=u^-\cdot \chi_{B(0,1/n)}$.

Why I think $(u^+)^q$ is not Fréchet differentiable is by the same idea... $u^-$ and $u^+$ has totally different support...

Comment: What is $\chi_{u^+}$?

Comment: The characteristic function of $u^+$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the characteristic function of a function? I know the definition of characteristic functions for sets...

Comment: I am sorry. I mean the Characteristic function of the support of $u^+$...

Comment: Ok and what is $B(0,1/n)$? Is this  ball in $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes. I wish to create a sequence of functions $v_n$ such that $v_n$ takes part of $u^-$ and $\|v_n\|$ goes to 0... some for my rush argument...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow your argument, however there is a more direct way to prove it. Do you know that every Frechet differentiable function is Gateaxu differentiable?

Comment: Yes, I know it. r u suggesting that $u^+$ is not Gateaxu differentiable?

Comment: Consider the Gateaux derivative of $E$ in the origin. Analyze two cases: $E(tv)/t$ with positive $t$ and $E(tv)/t$ wit negative $t$.

Comment: @Tomás I got it. Thank you! Also, I found an Theorem in Michael Struwe's book, on page 248 it has an nice theorem to characterize which functional is Frechet differentiability.

Comment: You are welcome. It is worth to note that the functional $E$ is $C^1$ for all $1<q\le2^\star$.

Comment: Also, it is $C^2$ for $2<q\le 2^\star$.